# How to add config file while pushing default docker image to cloud foundry

Tags: cloud-foundry, swisscomdev

As announced the Swisscom logstash [buildpack](https://github.com/swisscom/logstash-buildpack) is not supported any longer. 
The proposed solution is to push the default docker image. 
I am trying to figure out the way to attach the curator configuration without "baking" it inside the docker image. Any ideas?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are two articles in the support forum that discuss some aspects of your question here:

https://docs.developer.swisscom.com/service-offerings/logstash-docker.html
https://docs.developer.swisscom.com/service-offerings/kibana-docker.html

They do in fact recommend:

> If you wish to use configuration files instead, you can fork the official Docker image and `ADD` your configuration files in your own Dockerfile.

I assume that is exactly what you did not want to do, but you can pass in most of the config via environment variables as far as I understand.

If you are ok with creating a separate Docker image, you could also host the config somewhere (let's say on S3) and then dynamically retrieve it on start-up of your Docker container.

You could also build the config setup into your deployment setup, although I haven't tried this with the docker build-pack, you can "stack" multiple build-packs in CloudFoundry and pre-load your configuration files into the virtual server as part of an initial build-pack step. There is more information on how to do that here: https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/use-multiple-buildpacks.html